Nuxt3 server setCookie - cookie value does not change, what could be problem?
There is such an implementation of proxying requests to api, for reasons unknown to me, the value of the cookie that comes in the response does not change, but its parameters (for example httpOnly) change.
import { joinURL } from 'ufo';
import { parse as parseCookies } from 'set-cookie-parser';

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const { API_URI } = useRuntimeConfig();
  const path = event.path.replace(/^\/api\//, '');
  const url = joinURL(API_URI, path);

  return proxyRequest(event, url, {
    onResponse(event, response) {
      const combinedCookie = response.headers.get('set-cookie');

      if (combinedCookie) {
        const cookies = parseCookies(combinedCookie);

        cookies.forEach((cookie) => {
          const { name, value, ...options } = cookie;

          console.log('cookie', cookie);

          setCookie(event, name, value, {
            path: options.path,
            expires: options.expires,
            maxAge: options.maxAge,
            domain: options.domain,
            secure: options.secure || false,
            httpOnly: options.httpOnly || false,
          });
        });
      }
    },
  });
});


Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

I solved my problem using this method.


const event = useRequestEvent();

const res = await $fetch<{ accessToken: string }>('/api/auth/refresh', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie']),
  onResponse({ response }) {
    const cookies = response.headers.getSetCookie();

    if (cookies.length) {
      cookies.forEach((cookie) => {
        if (event) {
          appendResponseHeader(event, 'set-cookie', cookie);
        }
      });
    }
  },
});




Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

According to this document  Try this one
// server/api/endpoint.ts
import { appendResponseHeader } from "h3";

const res: any = await $fetch(url, { method, body, query, headers })
for (const cookie of res.headers.getSetCookie()) appendResponseHeader(event, 'set-cookie', cookie)
return res

